# How to create a trigger on a table that for each inserted row populates id with value from sequence in pl/sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
create or replace TRIGGER dept_id_trig

 BEFORE INSERT ON DEPARTMENTS


  FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE

BEGIN

  IF(:NEW.DEPARTMENT_ID IS NULL )

  THEN

   select DEPT_DEPTID_SEQ.nextval INTO :new.DEPARTMENT_ID FROM dual;

  END IF;

END;
```

Comment: So what's wrong with what you have there?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER dept_id_trig
  BEFORE INSERT ON DEPARTMENTS
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
    :new.DEPARTMENT_ID := DEPT_DEPTID_SEQ.nextval;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Oracle 12c or later, use an [`IDENTITY` clause on the column](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6) rather than a trigger:

```sql
CREATE TABLE departments(
  department_id NUMBER(10,0)
                GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
                CONSTRAINTS departments__department_id__pk PRIMARY KEY
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a trigger generated from Oracle itself when creating a new table:

```
create or replace TRIGGER dept_id_trig 
BEFORE INSERT ON DEPARTMENTS 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  <<COLUMN_SEQUENCES>>
  BEGIN
    IF INSERTING AND :NEW.DEPARTMENT_ID IS NULL THEN
      SELECT DEPT_DEPTID_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.DEPARTMENT_ID FROM SYS.DUAL;
    END IF;
  END COLUMN_SEQUENCES;
END;
```